# MySQL insert a field only if there's no duplicate TEXT field

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:
[image]
I'm inserting data from PHP. There should be no two rows with same `card` value. `card` field stores a json data with `mediumtext` type, and thus cannot be used as unique. What do I do?

Comment: you check to see if a row exists first

Comment: @Fred-ii- There could be up to 20 rows to insert per single request. Will that affect performance? Requests are triggering every minute as a cron task.

Comment: If your db's properly indexed, there shouldn't be a problem. MySQL can handle it no problem. Even still, a minute is nothing. MySQL can handle it by the second if needed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How can it "properly index" it?

Comment: You already have an AI'd column. A primary key should be enough. Note: Be careful with that `from` column; it's a reserved word. Try and stay away from using those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nice. But if there are 20? rows to insert, PHP have to check for existence of such field via db query, then wait for a response, then insert it, correct?

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/4566714/  and maybe this one too http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203844/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/32291180/ might help. and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4980801/